# How to execute python file from other directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems

I've got this structure:

```
│
├ main.py
├ dir
|  ├─ data.txt
|  └─ other.py
```

Contents from other.py:

```py
print(open('data.txt', 'utf-8').read())
```

I run `main.py`. It must start `dir/other.py`.
But `other.py` for works needs `data.txt`. Is there a way to start `other.py` from `main.py`, not editing `other.py`?

> **Note**
>   User must be able  to start other.py manualy without any errors

Comment: Is `other.py` to be imported as a module or run as a separate process?

Comment: It's not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use the import keyword. All you have to do is create an __init__.py script under the **dir** directory which will define the directory as a library. Then you can just use import others in the main script.

It is recommended to modify the others.py script with the below snippet

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    // do stuff
```

otherwise it will execute the library each time you import it

## update

It is far more simple. You just have to change directory with the **os.chdir("./dir")** call. After that you can run a simple import and the script will be executed.

```
./dir/other.py:
print("Module starts")
print(open('data', 'r').read())
print("Module ends")

./main.py
print("Main start")
import os
os.chdir("./dir")
from others import other
print("Main end" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import other in main file like `from dir.other import *`

Comment: Egh... I would have an error `No such file or directory: 'data.txt'`

Comment: To use data.txt which exists in dir from main.py you should use `'dir/data.txt'` as it is in dir directory not in same directory as main.py

Comment: I thought this at first. But the user sometimes could start `other.py` manually.